# Solution to Dirichlet Problem on Half-Disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given a Dirichlet problem

\begin{align} 
-\Delta u &= 0 \\ 
u(x_{1},0) &= 0 \quad \text{for } x \in [-1,1] \\ 
u(x_{1},\sqrt{1-x_{1}^{2}}) &= 1 \quad \text{for } x \in (-1,1) 
\end{align}

on the domain

$$\Omega = \{x=(x_{1},x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \lvert x \rvert^{2} < 1, \ x_{2} > 0 \}$$

How can I find $u$ in this case? I plugged in $x_{1} = r \cos \theta$ and $x_{2} = r \sin \theta$ and I suspect we should find the Green's function associated with the problem to find $u(r,\theta)$? But I am clueless on how to deal with this in polar coordinates, and since this is a half disk, I suspect that $-\pi<\theta<\pi$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use \ in for $\in$. Also, you can use \ to get a space between math objects when in dollar signs, or use \ quad to get four spaces, instead of using hspace all the time. Also, use \ sin and \ cos. Finally, in your question you haven't specified the domain of $x$ for $u(x_{1}, \sqrt{1 - x_{1}}) = 1$.

Comment: And are you sure its $\lvert x^{2} \rvert < 1$ and not $\lvert x \rvert^{2} < 1$ in the definition of $\Omega$?

Comment: you are absolutely correct, forgive me for all the errors and confusions of the question

Comment: I also think the condition should be $u(x_{1}, \sqrt{1 - x_{1}^{\color{red}2}}) = 1$. It seems you need to change the problem into polar coordinates first, [starting with the Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions). Then you'll probably want to use separation of variables.

Comment: So I set $r=\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}$ and $\theta=tan^{-1}(x_{2}/x_{1})$ and apply that to the boundary conditions in terms of $u(r,\theta)$ right? Do you mind walking me through the step by step calculation?